# SOA Architecture with WCF + IOC Structuremap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, structuremap, soa

I'm a little new to DI containers like StructureMap and I've been using it for a short time with asp.net mvc applications. Now I'm splitting my architecture that will have a WCF service layer and a sort of consumers like ASP.NET MVC app, Silverlight App, And Winfors/WPF App. When using SM with asp.net mvc I've been initializing the IOC by the app startup of the asp.net mvc, now, using for many project I can't think a good place where the IOC config should be located. 
I want to make DI in the services layer too(injecting Repositories).

In this scenario, where I do load my IOC config and how I'll use across the projects(like the controller factory is needed only in the asp.net mvc app)?

Comment: Sure, I'm open to others approaches  just said that I'll look more deeper in what he said, anyway. Anyone have another suggestion on the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create and configure a container **per application**.

If you have an ASP.NET MVC site, you create and configure a container instance in Global.asax.

In a WCF service you can write a custom `ServiceHostFactory` that spins up a custom `ServiceHost` that again attaches an appropriate `IInstanceProvider` that uses a container instance to wire up the WCF service. That sounds complicated, and it definitely is more complicated than it ought to be. I have previously touched on this subject in a completely different context, but [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2008/07/12/an-overview-of-unit-testing-duplex-wcf-services-and-clients.aspx) should give you some hints - particularly if you keep in mind that [delegates are anonymous interfaces](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/05/28/DelegatesAreAnonymousInterfaces.aspx).

Comment: I'll look at it, any news I'll post about. And thanks for the reply, following you at twitter right now =)

Comment: I just finished a 11-page detailed walkthrough about this for my upcoming book. Hopefully, it will be available through the MEAP in a month or two...